# Java Regex for matching a string

Tags: java, regex

I want a Java regex for:

> ACK : 2018-03-08 12:12:28 : 4802 : RETN=0,ID=1,NUM=9,RESULT=290,1,"sip:99990030@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990030",1,31,106,"0.0.0.0",0&291,1,"sip:99990031@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990031",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&292,1,"sip:99990032@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990032",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&293,1,"sip:99990033@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990033",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&294,1,"sip:99990034@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990034",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&295,1,"sip:99990035@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990035",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&296,1,"sip:99990036@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990036",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&297,1,"sip:99990037@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990037",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&298,3,"sip:99990039@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990039",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0
>   ACK : 2018-03-08 12:12:28 : 4802 : RETN=0,ID=1,NUM=2,RESULT=299,3,"sip:99990038@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990038",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&700,1,"sip:99990040@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990040",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0

that finds every single substring like:

> 290,1,"sip:99990030@192.30.32.68","**********"," 
>   ","99990030",1,31,106,"0.0.0.0",0

I tried

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(\\d+),(\\d+),\"sip:(.+)\",.+,.+,\"(\\d+)\",.+,.+,.+,.+,.+?&");
```

but that doesn't work.

Edit:
based on response I did it this way;

```
   Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile("(\\d+),(\\d+),\"sip:(.+)\",\".*\",\".*\",\"(\\d+)\",\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\".*\",\\d+");
   Matcher matcher;
   String teststr="................";
   String[] test2=teststr.split("&");
   List<String> result=new ArrayList<>();
   for(String s:test2){
    matcher=pattern.matcher(s);
    if(matcher.find()) result.add(matcher.group(0));
   }
   result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Edit 2:
Francesco's response also work's fine.
thanks all.

Comment: Please define 'does not work'

Comment: what should happen to the '>' characters? Also, do you need separate lines from your regex or a single text will do?

Comment: sorry Francesco they are mistakes happened because of copy/paste . i fiexd it

Comment: well if my answer satisfies you as well you can upvote it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly to test in the JShell, but in Scala, we have the String masking with """ some multiline String "which" contains quotes""", so I made it there:

```
val log = """ACK : 2018-03-08 12:12:28 : 4802 : RETN=0,ID=1,NUM=9,RESULT=290,1,"sip:99990030@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990030",1,31,106,"0.0.0.0",0&291,1,"sip:99990031@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990031",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&292,1,"sip:99990032@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990032",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&293,1,"sip:99990033@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990033",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&294,1,"sip:99990034@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990034",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&295,1,"sip:99990035@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990035",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&296,1,"sip:99990036@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990036",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&297,1,"sip:99990037@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990037",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&298,3,"sip:99990039@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990039",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0 ACK : 2018-03-08 12:12:28 : 4802 : RETN=0,ID=1,NUM=2,RESULT=299,3,"sip:99990038@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990038",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0&700,1,"sip:99990040@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990040",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0""" 

val parts = log.split ("&")

val lines = parts.map (s=> s.replaceAll (".*RESULT=", "") 
lines.foreach (println)
```

Result:

```
290,1,"sip:99990030@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990030",1,31,106,"0.0.0.0",0
291,1,"sip:99990031@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990031",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0
292,1,"sip:99990032@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990032",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0
293,1,"sip:99990033@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990033",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0
294,1,"sip:99990034@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990034",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0
295,1,"sip:99990035@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990035",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0
296,1,"sip:99990036@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990036",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0
297,1,"sip:99990037@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990037",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0
299,3,"sip:99990038@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990038",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0
700,1,"sip:99990040@192.30.32.68","**********"," ","99990040",1,31,101,"0.0.0.0",0
```

This follows the idea of "use the simplest thing which could possibly work".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you were too far:

```
\d{3},\d,\"sip:\d{8}@\d{3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}","\*{10}","[" ]","\d{8}",\d,\d{2},\d{3},"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}",\d
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/8dRdi1/2).

Of course, to incorporate it in Jave you can use

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regularExpression, Pattern.LITERAL);
```

so you won't have to escape all backslashes.